# How to run different methods parallely

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have one java method which contains 5 different internal methods. For performance improvement, I want to call these methods parallely.

e.g. run method1, method2, ... method5 parallel using thread.

```
private void getInformation() throws SQLException,
            ClassNotFoundException, NamingException {
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();
    method4();
    method5();
}
```

but all these 5 methods have different business logic.

Comment: Run each method under its own thread assuming that they share no mutable state ?

Comment: Thanks for this reply, could you please elaborate or give any example link :)

Comment: Here you go - http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Comment: Since you have identified that you need threads, what exactly is your question? How can you invoke new threads?

Comment: yes...because these are different business logic. and i dont know how to invoke threads for this

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do something like this:

1. For each method, create a Callable object that wraps that method.
2. Create an Executor (a fixed thread pool executor should be fine).
3. Put all your Callables in a list and invoke them with the Executor.

Here's a simple example:

```java
public void testThread()
{

   //create a callable for each method
   Callable<Void> callable1 = new Callable<Void>()
   {
      @Override
      public Void call() throws Exception
      {
         method1();
         return null;
      }
   };

   Callable<Void> callable2 = new Callable<Void>()
   {
      @Override
      public Void call() throws Exception
      {
         method2();
         return null;
      }
   };

   Callable<Void> callable3 = new Callable<Void>()
   {
      @Override
      public Void call() throws Exception
      {
         method3();
         return null;
      }
   };

   //add to a list
   List<Callable<Void>> taskList = new ArrayList<Callable<Void>>();
   taskList.add(callable1);
   taskList.add(callable2);
   taskList.add(callable3);

   //create a pool executor with 3 threads
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

   try
   {
      //start the threads and wait for them to finish
      executor.invokeAll(taskList);
   }
   catch (InterruptedException ie)
   {
      //do something if you care about interruption;
   }

}

private void method1()
{
   System.out.println("method1");
}

private void method2()
{
   System.out.println("method2");
}

private void method3()
{
   System.out.println("method3");
}
```

Make sure each method does not share state (like a common mutable field in the same class) or you may get unexpected results. Oracle provides [a good introduction to Java Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).  Also, [this book](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) is awesome if you are doing any kind of threading in java.

Comment: All is great and all except that nothing past `List<Future<Void>> futureList = executor.invokeAll(taskList);` will get executed, so those timers don't work.

Comment: invoking all methiods parallely but, its  creating thread-1 in method1 and thread-2 in method2 and so on.  It should create thread-1 for all methods. what we have to do. @Ireeder

Comment: and shutdown executor, here is possible?

Answer (score 7):

I had similar requirement. On a specific operation, I had to call some set of validator methods which in-turn validates certain components. Every validator used to take certain amount of time and had to reduce it and decided to call it in async.

Indeed there are many ways to achieve it, this is one of the approach which I solved.

Since validators mostly doesn't return any values, took advantage of Runnable class lambda. In below example `addition`, `multiply` and `subtraction` methods will be invoked asynchronously and in parallel.

```
public class MultiThreading {

        public static void addition() {
            System.out.println("Addition");
        }

        public static void multiply() {
            System.out.println("multiplication");
        }

        public static void subtraction() {
            System.out.println("subtraction");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

            Runnable callMultiply = () -> multiply();  //Create Runnable reference using lambda
            executor.execute(callMultiply);
            executor.execute(() -> addition()); //inline
            executor.execute(() -> subtraction());
            
            executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

To run method1 in parallel, do following:

```
Thread t1=new Thread() {
   public void run() {
       method1();
   }
};
t1.start();
```

Do this for all your methods.

To wait method1 to finish, do

```
t1.join();
```

and so for all other threads.

Many people will tell you *use threadpool* and *do not extend Thread* - all this has little sense for you just now. Master this way and only then follow that advices.

Comment: for all 5 method need to create 5 thread and inside run we need to call them which will make them call parallel ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use high level concurrency instrument in Java - thread pool. But anyway you will have to create Runnable objects (tasks) and then use thread pool's method - invokeAll(). Please take a look at [Oracle concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html)

Comment: but all these 5 methods have different business logic

Comment: @user1037452 So, what's the problem with using thread pool and "different business logic"? I don't fully understand your doubts. But it looks that you need to read some basic information about concurrency stuff in java

Answer (score 0):

take a look at java.util.concurrent
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html
and the tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/
basically, you will have to create an executorserice, some class extending Runnable, and invoke them

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 5 different threads to execute your methods in parallel, the code it's not difficult but pretty boring.

You may want to have a look to Gpars Tasks, which make writing parallel code much more easy and enjoyable.

http://gpars.org/1.0.0/guide/guide/dataflow.html#dataflow_tasks